# NoReverseMatch for Createview

Tags: python, django, url

I am using the CreateView (CBV) with a template that has a form to review lawyers.

When I try to use the URL routing in the template, I get this error:

```
Exception Value: Reverse for 'lawyerreview_create' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['fathers/lawyers/(?P<lawyerreview_slug>[\\w-]+)/createreview/$']
```

I would like to reverse to this URL, for example: fathers/lawyers/lawyer-name/createreview. But after two days of trying different things, I am no closer to that goal. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am not just looking for an answer, I humbly asking that someone ELI5 proper linking in django.

models:

```
class Lawyer(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
lawyer_slug = models.SlugField(default='')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Review(models.Model):
    lawyer = models.ForeignKey(Lawyer, null=True)
    review_title = models.CharField(max_length=69, default='')
    review_created = models.DateTimeField('Date of Review', auto_now_add=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    review_comment = models.TextField(default='')
    review_slug = models.SlugField(default='')
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

from .models import Lawyer, Review

class LawyerDetail(DetailView):
    model = Lawyer

    template = 'lawyer_detail.html'

    context_object_name = 'lawyers'

    def get_object(self):
        lawyer_slug = Lawyer.objects.get(
            lawyer_slug=self.kwargs.get('lawyer_slug')
        )
        return lawyer_slug

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LawyerDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['lawyer_review'] = self.object.review_set.all()
        return context


class LawyerReviewCreate(CreateView):
    model = Review
    fields = ['lawyer', 'rating', 'dos', 'review_comment']

class LawyerReviewUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Review
    fields = ['lawyer', 'rating', 'dos', 'review_comment']

class LawyerReviewDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Review
    success_url = reverse_lazy('lawyer_detail')
```

template.html (the section that generates the NoReverseMatch error)

```
{% if lawyer_review %}
    {% for review in lawyer_review %}
    <div class="review_buttom_wrapper">
        <button class="review_button" href="{% url 'lawyerreview_create' lawyer.lawyerreview_create %}">
            <strong>Review</strong> {{ review.lawyer.name }}
        </button>
    </div>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^lawyers/(?P<lawyer_slug>[\w-]+)/$', LawyerDetail.as_view(), name='lawyer_detail'),
    url(r'^lawyers/(?P<lawyer_slug>[\w-]+)/createreview/$', LawyerReviewCreate.as_view(), name='lawyer_createreview'),
    url(r'^lawyers/(?P<lawyer_slug>[\w-]+)/update/$', LawyerReviewUpdate.as_view(), name='lawyer_editreview'),
    url(r'^lawyers/(?P<lawyer_slug>[\w-]+)/delete/$', LawyerReviewDelete.as_view(), name='lawyer_deletereview'),
```

Error generated after using wobbily_col's solution:

```
Exception Value: Reverse for 'lawyerreview_create' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'lawyerreview_slug': ''}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Changed template to:

```
<button class="review_button" href="{% url 'lawyerreview_create' review.lawyer.lawyer_slug %}">
```

Getting this error now:

```
Exception Value: Reverse for 'lawyerreview_create' with arguments '('michael-ferrin',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

The lawyer's name is now showing up in the URL.

Edited template to this:

```
<a href="{% url 'lawyer_createreview' review.review_slug %}">
    <button class="review_button">
        <strong>Review</strong> {{ review.lawyer.name }}
    </button>
</a>
```

It is now properly linking to review_form template. However on submit, I get this error:

```
Exception Value: Reverse for 'lawyer_createreview' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'review_slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['fathers/lawyers/(?P<lawyer_slug>[\\w-]+)/createreview/$']
```

I was expecting to be routed back to the page that sent me to the review form.

Comment: What is value for parameter `lawyer.laywerreview_create` in `"{% url 'lawyerreview_create' lawyer.lawyerreview_create %}"`?

Comment: The problem is probably in urls.py, what have you got in there?

Answer (score 1):

The url tag takes the reverse name and arguments / keyword arguments as paramaters:

```
url(r'^lawyers/(?P<lawyerreview_slug>[\w-]+)/createreview/$', LawyerReviewCreate.as_view(), name='lawyerreview_create'),
```

so in this case it expects your urls name (lawyerview_create) and the lawyerreview_slug as a keyword argument. You are passing it a positional argument that doesn't seem to exist (lawyer.lawyerreview_create).

Pass the lawyer_slug in like this:

```
    <button class="review_button" href="{% url 'lawyerreview_create' lawyerreview_slug=lawyer_review.lawyer.lawyer_slug %}">
```

Comment: Sorry didn't work. I've simplified the code a bit using what you told me though.

Comment: It must be a different error, no? It should at least display the keyword arguments.